# Problems to import Geopandas

Tags: python

I'm trying to import geopandas to my Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda. The installation seems to work, however when I'm trying to import the package I have the following error :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e7e84a190af7> in <module>
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 import geopandas as gpd
      6 import matplotlib as mp
      7 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py in <module>
      2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
      3 
----> 4 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
      5 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis
      6 from geopandas.tools import sjoin

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in <module>
      1 import os
      2 
----> 3 import fiona
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import six

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py in <module>
     67 from six import string_types
     68 
---> 69 from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
     70 from fiona._drivers import driver_count, GDALEnv
     71 from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py in <module>
      7 
      8 from fiona import compat
----> 9 from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
     10 from fiona.ogrext import Session, WritingSession
     11 from fiona.ogrext import (

ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

I installed geopandas from forge :

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

The version installed is : geopandas 0.4.0 py_1 conda forge (I have also the version of fiona 1.7.10 py36hfa6e2cd_2).

I've already tried to install geopandas with different ways but it didn't change anything...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION** : I've found an other way to manage to install geopandas. What I did :

```
conda install fiona pyproj six
pip install geopandas
conda upgrade --all
```

And it works!